# play audio periodically from a memory stream c#

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, memorystream

I have some buffer containing samples of sinus which I want to be played from a memory stream periodically. Is there any efficient way to play it without having gaps in time? I try to make my own signal generator (I know that are some libraries providing that but I want to generate it by myself).

The platform is Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight

Update: the code is taken from this forum somewhere

```
public static void PlayBeep(UInt16 frequency, int msDuration, UInt16 volume = 16383)
    {
        var mStrm = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mStrm);
        const double TAU = 2 * Math.PI;           
        int samplesPerSecond = 44100;

        {
            double theta = frequency * TAU / (double)samplesPerSecond;
            // 'volume' is UInt16 with range 0 thru Uint16.MaxValue ( = 65 535)
            // we need 'amp' to have the range of 0 thru Int16.MaxValue ( = 32 767)
            double amp = volume >> 2; // so we simply set amp = volume / 2
            for (int step = 0; step < samples; step++)
            {
                short s = (short)(amp * Math.Sin(theta * (double)step));
                writer.Write(s);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "play randomly"? And show us your code.

Comment: I updated my post with code.
I mean randomly so the signal will play without stops until I tell him to stop

Comment: So you really mean "periodically"? E.g. a sustained tone without interruptions?

Comment: Ohh... Yes! that's what I mean, sorry about the misunderstanding

Comment: You can use the `PlayLooping` method. Just make sure that the wave in the stream is actually periodic - otherwise you'll have cracking and similar noises when it loops.

Comment: Hello, I target windows phone 8.1 silverlight and PlayLooping is a method of SoundPlayer class which is not there... I erased it from the code above(it was in the end of the code)

Comment: Oh... so what *are* you using to play the sound?

Comment: SoundEffect mySoundPlay = new SoundEffect(mStrm.ToArray(), 16000, AudioChannels.Mono);
           mySoundPlay.Play();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I did it - just create a new SoundEffectInstance object and set it to the return value of SoundEffect.CreateInstance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx

```
SoundEffect mySoundPlay = new SoundEffect(mStrm.ToArray(), 16000,AudioChannels.Mono);
SoundEffectInstance instance = mySoundPlay.CreateInstance();
instance.IsLooped = true;
instance.Play();
```